# How to structure html table

Tags: html

I'm trying to make a table that looks like the picture but i can't figure it out... This must be so easy question for you but I'm having trouble making this one work... can anyone help me? Please.

[image]

here is my current code for it:

```
<table width="100%" border="1">
<tr>
<th>Name of Candidates</th>
<th>Educational Attainment</th>
<th>Exprerience</th>
<th>In-Service Trainings & Seminars Attended</th>
<th>Eligibility</th>
<th>Other Qualifications</th>
<th>Interview</th>
<th>Total</th>
<th>Remarks</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: By using `colspan`, maybe?

Comment: Need a second row plus a columnspan.

Comment: How to proper use the colspan?? i use it but it disfigure my table.

Comment: http://html-tables.com/ This service very useful for this. Use merge button!

Comment: There is no obvious relationship between the “current code” and the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a combination of `rowspan` and `colspan`

**[example](http://jsfiddle.net/MErL8/1/)**

The first row will contain all the cells that takes 2 rows and 1 cell that spreads on 4 columns (gray background on the example). The second row will contain the 4 cells under the cell that spreads on 4 cells.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2"></td>
        <td colspan="4"></td>
        <td rowspan="2"></td>
        <td rowspan="2"></td>
        <td rowspan="2"></td>
        <td rowspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **colspan to increase width** of a cell:

```
colspan="4"
```

Documentation [colspan](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp)

---

Use **rowspan to increase height** of a cell:

```
rowspan="2"
```

Documentation [rowspan](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp)

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="7" rowspan="2"></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Its good helper for dificult table generator.
http://html-tables.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, use `colspan` to span multiple columns.

```
<table widtd="100%" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Name of Candidates</td>
        <td colspan="4">Educational Attainment</td>
        <td>Otder Qualifications</td>
        <td>Interview</td>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td>Remarks</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name of Candidates</td>
        <td>Educational Attainment</td>
        <td>Exprerience</td>
        <td>In-Service Trainings & Seminars Attended</td>
        <td>Eligibility</td>
        <td>Otder Qualifications</td>
        <td>Interview</td>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td>Remarks</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Similarly you could use `rowspan` for span multiple rows.